# How to set base url for sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube

I have used the helm charts for sonarqube
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/sonarqube

but I am using istio virtual service instead of ingress.

I want to set the base url to `mydomain.com/sonarqube`

Is that possible with sonarqube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont believe that there is a way. I ended up using `sonarqube.mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by setting a property:

```
# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# Changing this value and restarting the server can have unexpected consequences for logged in users,
# as they may end up with multiple conflicting browser cookies. If your users experience odd
# behaviors after you changed this value and restarted the server, ask them to clear their browser's
# cookies and log in again.
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=
```

See https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-application/src/main/assembly/conf/sonar.properties